# Is there a way to add a class or ID to revolution slider in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Is there a way to add a class or ID to the actual revolution slider (not slides) through their settings?

Answer (score 4):

If you go to **Slider settings > General Settings > Defaults**

You are able to set an ID for the slider:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to add it through settings.
However every slider has it's own ID. For example first slider that you create has ID rev_slider_1_1 second slider is #rev_slider_2_1 and so on.
To be sure you can always check ID of a slider with inspect element.

Maybe you can't add your own ID but most of the things can be solved by their own default ID's.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can give the class to the div that's enclosing your revolution slider.

E.g. if you're using visual composer to edit your wordpress pages, you can give class to the row or column or element added by visual composer.